# How can I configure VS Code to allow wildcard imports?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, configuration

We have a team currently developing a spring boot app, and I use VS Code, but other members use Intellij IDEA as development IDE. The issue is that when I pulled the project from the repository, opened it, and saved it, it expanded the wildcard imports automatically.

**In Intellij IDEA**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
```

**In VS Code**

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

Is there a way to configure VS Code to allow wildcard imports like IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you mean that when you open a script file written by someone else in vscode, it will automatically expand one line of import into multiple lines? Or do you automatically import multiple lines when editing the code yourself? Can you provide a [complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if there's a setting to make the extension leave such star imports as untouched. Looking through the list of settings, the only relevantly-named ones I found were the following (although perhaps I just missed some?):

```json
"java.sources.organizeImports.starThreshold": 99,
"java.sources.organizeImports.staticStarThreshold": 99
```

The settings' descriptions, respectively:

> Specifies the number of imports added before a star-import declaration is used.

> Specifies the number of static imports added before a star-import declaration is used.

Comment: Thank you that is worked. One thing I changed is the number from 99 to 5 because the intellij configured class count to use with import '*' to 5.